How to navigate (router.push()) when my context is updated inside a child component?
Here's my context provider. The child component will use setMyList to update myList .
// Context Provider

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
export let MyContext = createContext();

let initList = ['1']; // initial state

export default function MyProvider({ children }) {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState(initList);

  const context = { myList, setMyList };
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={context}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

What i want to do is update this context on a button click in the child component and then route to another path /another. (Edit: I actually need the state to update before navigation happens as /another needs the updated state.) However, since useEffect runs on the first render as well the page directly jumps to /another .
// Child Component
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from '../context-provider';

export default function Child() {
  let { myList, setMyList } = useContext(MyContext);
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(myList);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(myList);
    router.push('/another');
  }, [myList, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button type='button' onClick={() => setMyList([...myList, '2'])}>
        Update state and Navigate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

The only solution I can think of is comparing the current length of myList with whatever the previous length was before the state change. Is there another way of achieving this? Thanks!

It feels odd to me that the listener is in the child.  I'm assuming there would be multiple children, so then you'd have multiple listeners.   If you truly need to listen for state change it should be in the parent.   But, why aren't the children calling navigate on click? That seems to be the functionality you want.

I think I missed an important part of the puzzle - I need the state to change before navigation takes place as the next route will need the updated state. And yes, there will be only one 'child' component!

Here are two ways to solve this.
#1
We make the child component imperatively navigate when setting state.  I don't like the idea of multiple children listening to state and navigating when state changes, so I would completely remove the useEffect  from the children.

// Child Component
'use client';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { MyContext } from '../context-provider';

export default function Child() {
  let { setMyList } = useContext(MyContext);
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleUpdate = ()=>{
    setMyList((prev)=> ([...prev, '2']))
    router.push("/another")
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type='button' onClick={handleUpdate}>
        Update state and Navigate
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

#2
If you truly need to listen for state changes before navigating we can  make the parent more declarative.  We remove not only the useEffect but also the routing from the children and lift it all up to the parent.
// Context Provider

import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export let MyContext = createContext();

let initList = ['1']; // initial state

export default function MyProvider({ children }) {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState(initList);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(myList === initList) return;
    router.push("/another")
  },[myList, router, initList])

  const context = { myList, setMyList };
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={context}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

There are plenty of other ways to solve this as well.

Thank you! The second solution looks to be closer to what I was thinking (check the current array against the original array and navigate if they don't match). I wonder what's the issue with multiple children keeping track of the context though? This is the only component I was planning to have this functionality but I'm curious what's the issue with multiple children having it.

Oh and in the first solution, the updated state wouldn't immediately be available on the new route (/another), right?

The updated state will be available on next render, navigating and changing state both definitely cause a re-render.

The issue I see with multiple children listening to the state changes, is that they could all cause a navigation event to fire.  So 5 children will cause 5 navigation events.  If each child is navigating to a different route, that feels like a buggy race condition.  If the children need to fire the navigation event, then they need conditionals so that only one child actually fires the navigation event.
